# Catch the touch inside a shape drawn using CoreGraphics - ObjectiveC

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, events, core-graphics

I am drawing a shape using `Core Graphics` inside the `-(void) drawRect` method. How can I detect the touch inside that shape?

To make it simpler, when I touch the `UIView`, I should (atleast) be able to detect if the touch is inside the drawing.

How can I do this?

Comment: come on, guys. No one? Pls I really need this one.

Comment: chk this may be help you....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702898/core-graphics-line-drawing-and-deleting-on-touch

Comment: Did you get that sorted using UIBezierPath?

Answer (score 1):

Use `UIBezierPath` to define and draw your shape then you can use:

`- (BOOL)containsPoint:(CGPoint)point`

Comment: Can you expand on your answer please?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

Create a Touch Event:

```
- (IBAction)largeButtonDragInside:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [_myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(draging:withEvent:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchDragInside];    
}

- (void)draging:(UIControl *)c withEvent:ev {
    UITouch *touch = [[ev allTouches] anyObject];
    currentTouchPoint = [touch locationInView:_myButton];
    NSLog(@"Draging x: %f y: %f", currentTouchPoint.x, currentTouchPoint.y);
}
```

Update the location of the button according to the currentTouchPoint x & y.